# Can I use cursor keys for movement in Doom 2?

Tags: doom-2

I tried all keys and found that I can move with W/A/S/D, but a few decades of using the cursor keys makes it feel unnatural, probably because I am right handed.

Is there any way to use the cursor keys for movement?

Comment: If you have the original PC version, arrow keys should work as default. Keyboard controls can be changed with `setup.exe`.

Comment: I lost it many years, and many PCs, ago; which is why I had to buy it again on Steam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Steam version I believe you can run setup.exe with DosBox. There you can change keys however you like. Setup.exe is able to write to the default.cfg -config file. Setup.exe cannot be ran on Windows (hence the DosBox).

If for some reason you can't do this, you can edit the default.cfg file manually. This file has all the key bindings in it. Change the key codes to better suit your preferences. There's a small catch though, the key codes are actually scan codes and are hard to translate. Here is a guide to the scan codes: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa299374(v=vs.60)

Your default.cfg probably looks like this:

> key_right     77
>   key_left      75
>   key_up        17
>   key_down      31
>   key_strafeleft        30
>   key_straferight       32

Change the values to look like this:

> key_right     77
>   key_left      75
>   key_up        72
>   key_down      80
>   key_strafeleft        51
>   key_straferight       52

---

In Steam there might also be an option "Launch Doom with classic controls", but I can't confirm if it's true or not.

Comment: Ok, I see the `default.cfg` file. Which values correspond to the keyboard arrows? Alternatively, how do I run setup.exe with DosBox? It's so tantalizing when you tell me that these things can be done, but not how :-/

Comment: @Mawg Sorry, didn't mean to torment you. I've extended my answer. Hope you can manage with these instructions. Throw me a comment if you cannot pull it off or something doesn't work.

Comment: Thanx a 1,000,000. I am not sure if editting the .CFG fiel did it, or me suddenly noticing teh Steam option "Launch Doom 2 with classic contrails". Main thing - it works :-)

Comment: You're welcome! Both of them *should* work.